# Need help refactoring and speeding up if statement for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, refactoring, dry

I have the following Ruby on Rails code in my helper.  My views are slow loading when I have many links on the page.

Can anyone show me a refactored version that would be DRY and speed it up?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2afe1956e7565731ff20

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def link_to_doc(document)
    if document.document_type.downcase == "image"
      link_to "#{document.name}", "#{document.url}", class: "sublime"
    elsif document.document_type.downcase == "video"
      sublime_video_link_to(document)
    elsif document.url && document.url.length > 0
      link_to "#{document.name}", "#{document.url}", download: "#{document.name.parameterize}"
    elsif document.admin_url && document.admin_url.length > 0
     content_tag :a, href: document.admin_url do
       link_to "#{document.name}", document.admin_url
     end
    else
      link_to "#{document.name}", document_url(document)
    end
  end

  def btn_link_to_doc(document)
    if document.document_type.downcase == "image"
      link_to "View #{ document.document_type.downcase }", "#{document.url}", class: "document-link btn sublime"
    elsif document.document_type.downcase == "video"
      sublime_video_btn_link_to(document)
    elsif document.url && document.url.length > 0
      link_to "Download #{ document.document_type.downcase }", "#{document.url}", download: "#{document.name.parameterize}", class: "document-link btn"
    elsif document.admin_url && document.admin_url.length > 0
     content_tag :a, href: document.admin_url do
       link_to "View", document.admin_url, class: "document-link btn"
     end
    else
      link_to "View", document_url(document), class: "document-link btn"
    end
  end  


private


  def sublime_video_btn_link_to(document)
     tag=[]
      tag<<link_to("View #{ document.document_type.downcase}", "#video#{document.id}", class: "document-link btn sublime", data: { settings: 'close-button-visibility:visible' })  
      tag<<  content_tag(:video,{ id: "video#{document.id}", style: "display:none;", width:'480', height:'270', preload: true }) do
              content_tag(:source, nil,{src: document.url}) 
             end
      tag.join.html_safe
  end

  def sublime_video_link_to(document)
     tag=[]
      tag<<link_to("#{document.name}", "#video#{document.id}", class: "sublime", data: { settings: 'close-button-visibility:visible' })  
      tag<<  content_tag(:video,{ id: "video#{document.id}", style: "display:none;", width:'480', height:'270', preload: true }) do
              content_tag(:source, nil,{src: document.url}) 
             end
      tag.join.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you used any profiling tools to check that it is actually these helpers and not something else? The profiling tool might also help you find out what part of those are causing the problem.

Comment: Do you mind copying and pasting your code to your initial question? I don't mind clicking and looking at the code, but Stack Overflow conventions dictate having the code right in the question (besides, it'll probably encourage more ppl to look and answer!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of these double checks

```
    document.admin_url && document.admin_url.length > 0
```

you can use

```
   document.url.to_s.blank?
```

it will check for nil and empty strings

Comment: Changing to .blank? improved performance greatly. However,the page load time is still 1.5 sec and mostly from the if statement because it is running through a list and repeating the function over and over for each document. so I'm trying to improve it further. any more recommendations?

Comment: it depends on how long this list is , but you can them some tips and see if they can help
array.compact! **will remove all nils in the array**
array.flatten! **make on array of it is array of arrays**
array.uniq! **remove all repeated items**

Comment: also you can use 2 methods **delete_if** and if you filter most of the array user **keep_if**